# Is there any selector to do a perfect match against text?

Tags: jquery

On jQuery, I'm looking to a similar selector to `:contains` but I need to do a perfect match against an element text. Is there any?

```
<div>1</div>
<div>12</div>
<div>13</div>
<div>135</div>
```

so If I look for `text = 1` I would only get the first `div`

Comment: Are you looking for the innerHTML of an element like a div, or the value of an element like an input field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done so:

```
var str = "whatever";

$(".elements").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == str;
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't `return $(this).text() == string` be more appropriate, since `innerHTML` will look at the HTML structure as well as the text-content?

Comment: @DavidThomas Yeah.. I think you are right. For general solution it is better. Thanks!

Comment: While the answer works, I'm genuinely surprised that this was accepted over Jonathan Sampson's. =/

Comment: For my specific scenario this is the best solution. I agree that It might worth to create a selector as Jonathan Sampson suggest in order to using it on different places.

Answer (score 11):

You can make one:

```
$.extend($.expr[":"], {
    exactly: function( element, index, details, collection ){
        return $(element).text() === details[3];
    }
});

$("div:exactly(Foo)").addClass("red");
$("div:exactly(230)").addClass("blu");
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/YUQLF/

Comment: Ooooh...that's pretty awesome.

Comment: @Jonathan Sampson: this seems good enough. I thought I was missing a builr in option. Thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you point to the documentation for this approach? It's one I've never (so far as I can recall) seen before.

Comment: @TimmyO'Tool This is not a built in option. In this solution Jonathan created `:exactly` selector by himself.

Comment: And yes, that is pretty awesome.

Comment: @thecodeparadox That's some kind of overloading. What are you talking about?

Comment: @DavidThomas and j08691 I'm going to write something up - I'll let you know when it's available.

Comment: @DavidThomas Now available: http://sampsonblog.com/279/creating-your-own-custom-jquery-filters

Comment: @j08691 Please see the link in the last comment for an explanation.

Comment: @JonathanSampson - awesome, thanks. Maybe you should post a question here like, "How can I create a custom jQuery filter?" and post your blog post as the answer. I'd +1 it ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
var search = '1';
$('div').filter(function() {
  return $(this).text()  == search;
}).css('background','#f00');
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/LUrep/3/)**

Comment: if the text is `12` and I look for `1` contains would match unless I'm missing something. That's not what I'm looking for, I need to do a perfect match.

Comment: @TimmyO'Tool check the demo, it's doing same what you want

Comment: @thecodeparadox: at the moment I said that your answer wasn't what I needed you had a totally different code. VisioN already posted this solution. Thanks anyway!