# Hide all 'a' elements with text or innerHTML that matches the number '0' or a custom value using javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, match, innerhtml

I need to Hide all `<a>` elements with text or `innerHTML` that matches the number 'foo' or a custom value using javascript or jQuery.

```
<li><a href="#" class="dir">foo</a></li>
```

I have tried

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    if (jquery().text().html("foo"){
        ('li >a').fadeOut()
    }
});
```

Answer (score 14):

```
$('a:contains(foo)').hide();
```

Done.

Or:

```
var customValue = "foo"
$('a').filter(function(){
    return this.innerHTML === customValue;
}).fadeOut();
```

With the later option you custom it a lot more, like:

```
var customValue = "foo"
$('a').filter(function(){
    return this.innerHTML === customValue &&
           $(this).closest('div').length;
}).fadeOut();
```

Answer (score 3):

One approach, assuming the text you're searching for is *exactly* the string you use, <sub>shamelessly stealing from</sub> **paying homage to** [Jonathan Sampson](http://sampsonblog.com/279/creating-your-own-custom-jquery-filters):

Creating the `:exactly` selector:

```
$.extend($.expr[":"], {
    exactly: function( element, index, details, collection ){
        return $(element).text() === details[3];
    }
});
```

Used like so:

```
$('a:exactly("foo")').fadeOut();
```

References:

- Jonathan Sampson:

  - The blog entry for `:exactly()` selector: http://sampsonblog.com/279/creating-your-own-custom-jquery-filters
  - The Stack Overflow question that prompted the creation of `:exactly()`: [Is there any selector to do a perfect match against text?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10821326/82548)

Comment: Your `:exactly` extension always returns `true`; might want to fix that.