# jquery regex trim beginning and end of a url string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have links with href attributes that look like this:

http://company.com/inetucm/groups/public/@enterprise/documents/pagecontent/s_014654.html

I want to write a jquery function that sets just the **s_014654** to a variable, that I will use later to create a different url stucture.

Can someone please help me with that syntax.

Comment: What do you mean by "a jQuery function"? Are you talking about creating a plugin? If you just want a re-usable function simply take either of the answers so far and encapsulate them in a standard function...

Comment: We have a debate over here, can you please tell us which of the two ways is easier for you to understand?

Comment: Are you still having troubles? if not you should accept one of the answers. ([Writing _"Accept"_ seems to be broken though](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10923130/601179))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var url = ....;
var arr = url.split('/');
var value = arr.pop().match(/^(.+)\.html$/)[1];
alert(value); // "s_014654"
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Fjp8E/1)

---

Update: (based of the comment)

```
<a href="http://company.com/inetucm/groups/public/@enterprise/documents/pagecontent/s_014654.html" />
<a href="http://company.com/inetucm/groups/public/@enterprise/documents/pagecontent/AAAAAAAA.html" />
<a href="http://company.com/inetucm/groups/public/@enterprise/documents/pagecontent/BBB.html" />    
<a href="http://company.com/inetucm/groups/public/@enterprise/documents/pagecontent/fdskl489j.html" />
```

**jQuery:**​

```
var arr = $('a').map(function(){ 
    return this.href.split('/').pop().match(/^(.+)\.html$/)[1]; 
}).get();
```

This will return all the values in an array.

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Fjp8E/4)

Comment: You can also do `arr.pop().match(` :-P

Comment: @zerkms. Yes, it's easier to read and understand, but it can be done with regex as well...

Comment: @gdoron: are you sure that replacing `.+` with `[^/]+` changes much --- http://stackoverflow.com/a/10923281/251311 ? Meanwhile - we need to think of `split` + `pop`

Comment: @zerkms. For you me and nnnnn it might not, but for beginners it sure might be a big change. Don't you agree?

Comment: @zerkms. I can add add `indexOf` to that list instead of `regex` if you like to. `:)`

Comment: @gdoron: nope I don't agree, that adding `split` and `pop` with "easier" regex is easier for beginner to understand, just because you need to keep in mind execution of 3 functions, not 1 ;-)

Comment: @zerkms. I asked the OP; It's interesting question, even more then the OP question... :)

Comment: `value = url.slice(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1, url.lastIndexOf('.'));` does it without any regex if you want to make it _really_ easy for beginners...

Comment: @nnnnnn. But now you don't have `split` and `pop` so... it doesn't worth a thing. :)

Comment: @nnnnnn: imho the easier solution (in this case) is the one that uses less functions. And it is `url.match()`

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have been more clear. I'm going to do this on a page with lots of links:

$('a').each(function(){
  //get and trim the querystring out of the url
  
  //replace the href on each link with a cleaned url thatlooks like http://company.com/articleId=querystring

});

Comment: @user1043804. O.K. What is the problem with it?

Comment: @zerkms. You ought to [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10923130/601179). Yes it's off-topic, but damn it's funny!

Comment: @user1043804. You can use: `$('a').map(function(){ return this.href.split('/').pop().match(/^(.+)\.html$/)[1]; });`

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
var url = "http://company.com/inetucm/groups/public/@enterprise/documents/pagecontent/s_014654.html";

var value = url.match(/([^/]+)\.html$/)[1];
```

With thanks to gdoron for the fiddle that I updated with my own regex: http://jsfiddle.net/Fjp8E/2/

The pattern `([^/]+)\.html$` looks for one or more non-slash characters that are followed by ".html" at the end of the string.

Comment: Just worth saying, the `regex` grabs every char that doesn't have a slash **and** ends with `.html`. +1.

Comment: You ought to [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10923130/601179), that guy is so funny! I'm sorry, but I had to share it with someone...